# Is there a simpler or shorter way to prove (or disprove) the trigonometric identity?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

I want to prove:

$\dfrac{1+\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta} =\dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta} $

And I think I have it, but, even though I double checked, it can be seen it's a little mess. Maybe somebody can corroborate. And if true, is there a simpler way to prove it?

Start manipulating the LHS:

$\dfrac{1+\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta}=$

$\dfrac{(1+\cos(\alpha+\beta))(1-\cos(\alpha+\beta))}{(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta)(1-\cos(\alpha+\beta))}=$

$\dfrac{1-\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)}{(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta)(1-\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta)}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\beta\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\sin\beta+\cos\beta\sin\alpha\sin\beta}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos\alpha(1-\cos^2\beta)+\cos\beta(1-\cos^2\alpha)+\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\sin\beta+\cos\beta\sin\alpha\sin\beta}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos\alpha\sin\beta\sin\beta+\cos\beta\sin\alpha\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\sin\beta+\cos\beta\sin\alpha\sin\beta}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos\alpha\sin\beta(\sin\beta+\sin\alpha)+\cos\beta\sin\alpha(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{(\cos\alpha\sin\beta+\cos\beta\sin\alpha)(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta)}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}$

Comment: $\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{1 + \cos(\alpha + \beta)} = \tan(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})$, whereas $\sin \alpha + \sin \beta = 2 \sin(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}) \cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})$ and $\cos \alpha + \cos \beta = 2 \cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}) \cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})$.  Would need to be careful of the case when $\cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}) = 0$ though.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html  and http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I knew them and I tried that way, but didn't succeed, anyway I got the idea that there were some shorter way. By the way, is this identity often used? its, say, symmetry suggest usefulness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go the following way: assuming that neither $\sin\alpha+\sin\beta$ or $\cos\alpha+\cos\beta$ are zero, the given equation is equivalent to

$$ \sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\alpha\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\sin\beta\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\cos\beta \sin(\alpha+\beta) $$
that follows from the sine addition formulas:
$$ \sin\alpha = \sin((\alpha+\beta)-\beta) = \sin(\alpha+\beta)\cos\beta-\sin\beta\cos(\alpha+\beta)$$
$$ \sin\beta = \sin((\alpha+\beta)-\alpha) = \sin(\alpha+\beta)\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha\cos(\alpha+\beta).$$
Three lines and we are done.